# Transactions .NET

Tags: .net, transactions

I've just begon using Transactions in .NET and I have a problem. In a function (in my DAL) I use a transaction scope. On the end of the function I trigger the Complete() function.

Now I have a test for this function which also uses a transaction scope. On the end of this test function I do not trigger the complete() function so that my test doesn't fill the database with test data. This seems to be working fine.

My problem now is that if I do trigger complete() in my test function, the transaction seems to be completed twice. This seems logical as I trigger Complete() twice... but is there a way to avoid this? Is there a way to trigger the Complete() function twice without executing the scope twice... Sure there must be a way to nest transactions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand [nested transaction scopes](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimjohn/archive/2005/06/18/11451.aspx) and the [TransactionScopeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you Dispose without calling Complete the transaction will be rolled, also TransactionScope [supports nested transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845517/nested-transactions-with-transactionscope). Mix and match and you should be able to roll back all the work your tests do.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your inner TransactionScope with the RequiresNew option:

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)
```

Comment: Thx, I will first look into these nested transactions and the TransactionScopeOption. I tried the RequiresNew which solves my previous problem but this raises new problems.