# Nested Transactions with TransactionScope

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

If you have somehting like this:

```
IBinaryAssetStructureRepository rep = new BinaryAssetStructureRepository();
var userDto = new UserDto { id = 3345 };
var dto = new BinaryAssetBranchNodeDto("name", userDto, userDto);
using (var scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var scope2 = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Persist to database
        rep.CreateRoot(dto, 1, false);
        scope2.Complete();
    }
    scope1.Dispose();
}
dto = rep.GetByKey(dto.id, -1, false);
```

Will the inner TransactionScope scope2 also be rolled back?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

The inner transaction is enrolled in the same scope of the outer one, and the whole thing will rollback. This is the case, as you didn't enroll the inner transaction as a new one using TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew.

Answer (score 7):

See here for an explanation on this subject: http://web.archive.org/web/20091012162649/http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimjohn/archive/2005/06/18/11451.aspx.

Also, note that the `scope1.Dispose` is redundant since `scope1` will be automatically disposed at the end of the `using` block that declares it.

Comment: You say scope.Dispose is redundant, but more importantly scope1.dispose rolls back the transaction.