# Trouble understanding TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

Given following code structure

```
func1()
{
    using (TransactionScope1)
    using (connection1)
    {
        "insert into table A"

        func2()

        "select from table B"
    }
}

func2()
{
    using (TransactionScope2)
    using (connection2)
    {
        foreach (x in y)
        {
            "select from table A"
            "insert into table B"
        }
    }
}
```

If `TransactionScope2` was rolled back, then `"select from table B"` fails with `The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction`. As I understand `TransactionScope2` is joining with the first one and rolls them both back. 
So I changed it to create it with `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`, which in turn results in timeout on `"select from table A"`.

The idea is to let second transaction read data from first one, but commit/rollback independently. My guess is `IsolationLevel` needs to change somehow, but I don't really understand the options for it.

**EDIT:**
Perhaps it is easier to understand the problem if we name the `func1` and 2. Basically `func2` is a DAL functionality, and and `func1` is a unit test for it. `func1` creates some sample data, gets `func2` to perform some actions on it, checks the result then rolls the entire thing back regardless of wherever `func2` was successful or not.

**EDIT2:** after reading up some more I think the following code should work, but for some reason I still get timeouts on `select from table A`

```
func1()
{
    using (var txn = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
    using (connection1)
    {
        "insert into table A"
        func2()
        "select from table B"
    }
}

func2()
{
    using (var txn = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    using (connection2)
    {
        foreach (x in y)
        {
            "select from table A"
            "insert into table B"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say you should take 'select from table B' out of the transaction scope

Comment: @Felix my bad, the second insert should've been "insert into table B". There is no table C - I just made a mistake typing it in.

Comment: I think you need ReadUnCommitted on the inner transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [nested TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845517/nested-transactions-with-transactionscope).

By default they are linked, without further action ([RequiresNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y1642)) from you, the outer scope will fail (RollBack) when the inner one does.

This way they will be independent:

```
func2()
{
    using (TransactionScope2 = 
         new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)) 
    using (connection2)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: By inserting in table A you are locking a part of table A, therefore in func2() you are trying to read table A, which will wait until the lock is released, which will not happen. Hence the timeout. The solution is probably to use a different isolationlevel, as suggested my muratgu.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`.

Comment: the above is happening if I set both transactions to `ReadUncommitted`. I would expect that if I simply set outer one to `ReadUncommitted` and inner one to `RequresNew` it should just work, but for some reason I still get timeout on `select from table A`

Comment: Have you tried setting both transactions to be RequiresNew and ReadUncommitted? I don't see that in your current posted code.